# Indexing and querying int value from JSON array in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, database-indexes

I want to create a table with a column containing `jsonb` data-type. 
What would be the proper way to index and query a int value in an array?

Entry:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "type": "FOO",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "type": "BAR",
      "value": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

2 different queries, I want to find all entries which contain a list-item,

- Type = 'FOO' AND value > 500
- value > 100

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 10+

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to index any of the `>` comparisons, but the equality condition can be indexed:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tabname USING gin (jsonbcol jsonb_path_ops);
```

This can be used by a query like the following:

```
SELECT id FROM tabname
WHERE jsonbcol @> '{ "list": [ {"type": "FOO"} ] }';
```

If you plan to use JSON attributes heavily inside the database, you are doing something wrong. Keep the attributes you want to index in regular database columns. In your case, that would be a separate table that links to your table with a foreign key, so that there can be several entries for each row.